# Certifying an Actions On Google Smart Home App

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

my app has passed the first review (yay) - but has now been passed to Allion for 'hardware review'. 
The issue is that I am not providing hardware, i've provided voice interactions for an open source HA system, which in turn can support 00s of device types. 
The Amazon review process was happy for me to provide them credentials to my service, which had access to a subset of device types, to then QA the interactions. 
Is this normal for the review process?

Answer (score 0):

Thus far many of the supported services have been direct hardware partners who own their own hardware and cloud. If your integration is done in a slightly different way it may require special instructions to your reviewer that may be different from normal.

Comment: I'm working with them - but what should be a very easy process for them (no need to setup/test hardware) is clearly a problem for them. Disappointing

Answer (score 0):

I have had further comment from Google. Unless I can provide 1 of every type of physical device that the underlying HA system supports, they will not review, or certify my app. What this tells me is that either Google aren't committed to small SaaS providers & HA enthusiasts, or that this comment is not true. I note that there are several equivalent services listed on Smart home app list, which do exactly the same thing as mine. I rather doubt they provided one of every manufacturers zwave switch/light etc etc. Very disappointing, Amazon have a more welcoming approach –